# how to LINQ query show repeated records That 2 or less than twice repeated

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have one table like this :

```
---------------------------------------
|       Name       |       code       |     
---------------------------------------
|       Sam                01         |
|       Sam                01         |
|       Sam                01         |
|       Dani               02         |
|       Dani               02         |
|       Vector             03         |
|       vector             03         |
|       vector             03         |
|       Sara               04         |
---------------------------------------
```

I need to show recordings that have been repeated, for example, 2 or less than 2 times

```
result : (Records <= 2)

    Dani               02 
    Dani               02
    Sara               04
```

my LINQ query select from two tables and conditions :

```
var result = (from ArdSamanehs in _entity.ArdSamanehs
           join TableExcels in _entity.TableExcels
           on new { ArdSamanehs.Cardex, DorehNo = 
           (string)ArdSamanehs.DorehNo }
           equals new { Cardex = TableExcels.CardexN, DorehNo = "12" }
                      group new { ArdSamanehs, TableExcels } by new
                      {
                          ArdSamanehs.NameFamily,
                          ArdSamanehs.Doreh,
                          ArdSamanehs.CityDesc,
                          TableExcels.CardexN,
                          ArdSamanehs.Cardex,
                          ArdSamanehs.Date
                      } into g

                      orderby
                        g.Key.NameFamily

                      select new
                      {
                          g.Key.NameFamily,
                          g.Key.Doreh,
                          g.Key.CityDesc,
                          g.Key.Date
                      }).ToList();
```

How to LINQ my Query in c#?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

```
  var lists = result.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Code})
                              .Where(x => x.Count() <= 2).SelectMany(x => x)
                              .ToList();
```

Comment: I have updated answer it comes the list of records.

Comment: What've your results come?

Comment: i want use your query inside my query i edited my post pls help me